# Que significa "o dia já está lindo"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

O que significa isto?

> O dia já está lindo!

Quer dizer:

> o dia já começou?

Comment: A interrogação na segunda frase é proposital? O significado da primeira é direto, "The day is already lovely/beautiful!" (o "já" talvez se refira a uma expectativa de mais tarde melhorar).

Comment: @stafusa   Eu entendo o "já" como: "o dia começou lindo" ou  "já tão cedo e já tão lindo"

Comment: @Centaurus Sim, poderia também ser, essa situação é bem semelhante à que mencionei: o "á tão cedo e já tão lindo" implica uma antecipação de que ficaria bonito (apenas) mais tarde.

Comment: O dia já está lingo sugere: O dia já ficou lindo. Estava chovendo, por exemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em geral, *o dia já está lindo* significa que o dia agora está lindo e antes não estava. O que é um dia lindo pode ser um pouco subjetivo, mas a maioria das pessoas acha que um dia lindo é um dia com sol, por oposição a um dia com o céu todo coberto de nuvens.

Portanto, imagina que o céu estava todo nublado, e depois as nuvens começam a desaparecer, e o sol aparece. Um pessoa poderia então dizer: “o dia já está lindo” — antes não estava lindo, mas agora já está.

Agora, eu consigo imaginar um situação diferente. Imagina que alguém acorda de manhã, não sabe as horas, tem as janelas completamente fechadas e por isso não sabe se ainda é noite ou se já é dia, acende a luz, levanta-se, abre uma janela e vê que o sol já nasceu e que o dia está lindo. Então podia voltar-se para o companheiro e dizer, “acorda, meu dorminhoco, que o dia já está lindo”. Pelo contexto, compreende-se que ela quer dizer que já é dia (a noite já acabou e o dia já começou), mas não só; ela quer dizer que já é dia e também que o dia está lindo. Se ela quisesse simplesmente dizer que o dia já tinha começado, diria só “já é dia”, “já é de dia” ou “já está de dia”.

Comment: Eu entendo o "já" como: "o dia começou lindo" ou "já tão cedo e já tão lindo".  Eu não usaria o "já" às quatro horas da tarde.

Answer (score 1):

The expression "the day is already beautiful!" it means that "the day has already begun", because the night represents the darkness and the day the light, so the people ended up relating day (light) to beauty and night or cloudy weather to melacolia or sadness, hence we have the expression "the day is sad".
As we have "the day is already beautiful" and not "the day is beautiful" so it means that "the day has already started", being used early in the morning.

A expressão o "dia já está lindo!" quer dizer que "o dia já começou", pois a noite representa a escuridão e o dia a luz, logo os povos acabaram relacionando dia(claridade) à beleza e noite ou tempo nublado à melancolia ou tristeza, daí temos a expressão "o dia está triste".
como temos " o dia já está lindo" e não "o dia está lindo" assim significa que  "o dia já começou", sendo usado logo de manhã.

Answer (score 0):

Significa que ele não está da mesma forma do dia anterior, na frase mostra que ele está melhor, se falando em clima e bem estar.